# How to sort order after adding or changing the value?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, yii

I need to sort a list of items shown in images below

Conditions:
1. Sort order must be in **continuous order**
2. Multiple value should not be allowed.

The problem i encountered was when i change the value from 3 to 4 and there are two shows  with value 4

How can i overcome this problem in PHP-yii? I would appreciate if anyone would help me with the **logic** involved in this.

[image]

After the change 
[image]

Comment: What do you want it to do? What should the new value for "Student Life" be in your example? A quick and dirty solution would be to just swap the value with the one you just changed - but I don't think this is a very user friendly one..

Comment: swapping value is not work in this case, i need like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.when changing one value order need to update without changing previous order 1-2 in example and swap 3 and 4 then incremented value5-9

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this up into 2 operations.

`move` takes a given item (eg item 3), and sends it to a given position (eg #5) and then shifts everything between by one.

`renumber` takes the sorted list, and changes all of the displayed numbers.

I would do this in JavaScript, so in an `onchange` you `move` the changed element to its new position.  Then `renumber` unconditionally.

If you are doing it server side, you can store hidden form fields with the original positions, figure out each change, jump over and over again, then reorder at the end.  This will be more confusing to work out, and will be a worse user interface.  (Hence why I'd push this client side.)